# How to access other elements in root view from partial view with JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, view, show

I have a partial view with some JQuery...

```
    $("#btnCancelPayment").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('#test').show('fast');
        $(this).closest("#paymentSection").hide('fast');
    });
```

And this partial view sits in the div with id of paymentSection in the root view... wondering how I can find other elements on the root view other than the paymentSection div... (the hide above works, but the show doesn't). The root view:

```
<div id="test">testing </div>

<div id="paymentSection"></div>
```

It's JQuery...

```
$("#btnYesPayment").click(function () {
   ....
        $("#paymentSection").load('/Donation/AddPaymentInfo', function () {
            $("#paymentSection").show('fast');
            $('#spinner').hide();
        });
    });
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: by any chance you have multiple `ids`? if yes then remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
 $(this).closest('#test').show('fast');
```

to

```
if($('#test').length>0){
 $('#test').show('fast');
}else console.log('there is no such element');
```

Comment: thanks, this was useful. My code was sloppy to begin with, this helped.